# Swift, Trouble Instantiating NSCoding Compliant Class

Tags: swift, nscoding

Ive been hitting a roadblock with NSCoding. Specifically, instantiating a class that conforms to NSCoding. Maybe I'm missing something really obvious, but I haven't found any answers yet.

```swift

```
class TitleTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {



required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Neue", size: 25)

}
```

```

This is just one example, a simple one. When I try to instantiate this class elsewhere, i.e  something like "let textField = TitleTextField()"  (sorry can't figure out how to format that)  I get the error "missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call". When I try to fix it with the suggested  TitleTextField(coder: NSCoder)  it throws an error and tells me to delete "coder:", then it throws another error and says "Cannot convert value of type '(NSCoder).Type' (aka 'NSCoder.Type') to expected argument type 'NSCoder'"

How do I instantiate this class?

This gave me trouble on a custom class I created that conformed to NSCoding as well after following several different examples to a T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really simple - you need to add another designated initializer, typically `init(frame:)` for `UIView`. You can actually just call `super.init(...)` in it.

The problem is that once you add one initializer, the other initializers stop being inherited from superclass and you have to define them.

Comment: I dont understand what UIView has to do with it

Comment: @R.P.Carson `UITextField` is a subclass of `UIView` and the initializers come from `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Neue", size: 25)
}
```

This code worked for me. Seems you missed optional in func declaration

```
public class UIView : UIResponder {
    public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what UIView has to do with it. And the code compiles, I just cant make an instance of TitleTextField

Comment: It was just code copy-paste from the UIView interface to show the `required init` implementation.